# How to generate curl command using C#

Tags: c#, json, salesforce

I'm working on Salesforce and wanting to get cases fields in it. found the command

```
curl https://yoursite.desk.com/api/v2/cases \
-u email:password \
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

And I tried it in command prompt as

```
curl https://xxx.desk.com/api/v2/cases \-u abc@gmail.com:xxxxxxxxx \ -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

I have tried the below code in C#

```
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.desk.com/api/v2/cases");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

But it is returning an error

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx.desk.com/api/v2/cases");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic reallylongstring");
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        string text;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {            
                string fddf =  streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

CURL is just a client for WebRequests

the default C# option is 
[WebRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx)
you can also use [Restsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)

Comment: I cannot do your work for you. Those are the tools.  There are examples and tutorials. If u are stuck with a new question ask.